# Many-to-many relationships without a linking table/model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model `User` and a model `Thing`. A `User` can own zero or more `Thing`s. A `Thing` may be owned by zero or more `User`s. Ordinarily I would add in a third table `Thing_Ownership` linking `User`s to `Thing`s but I would like to take advantage of SQLAlchemy's backref feature so that if I had a `User` instance `george` I could call `george.inventory` to get a list of `Thing`s that belong to `george`.

What is the best way to go about this, or should I just add a third model and implement `User.inventory` as a search through a third `Thing_Ownership` model for relevant relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out SQLAlchemy's documentation on [Many to Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) relationships - it should do exactly what you're looking for.

So if you have models for `User` and `Thing`, you can set up a secondary parameter in your relationship:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Integer, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')),
    Column('thing_id', Integer, ForeignKey('thing.id'))
)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    # Whatever you need in this model
    inventory = relationship('Thing', secondary = association_table, backref = 'users')

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    # Whatever you need in this model
```

You can then access a list of `Thing`s belonging to a `User` instantiated as `george` by calling `george.inventory`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Reread your question and saw you wanted to use `backref` - added code to do that.
EDIT 2: Left out a really important part.